# Iterative Hash Algorithm for Fast File Check

Tags: algorithm, hash

I want to create a representation of the state of all files in a folder (ignoring order), so that I can send this state to another computer to check if we are in sync. This "state representation" is 3 numbers concatenated by `.` which are:

```
sum . product . number of items
```

The "sum" is the numerical addition all of the file's md5 numerical representations.

The product is the multiplication of all of the file's md5 numerical representations.

The number of items is just the number of files.

The main reason for doing this is that this allows me to create **unique** states **iteratively/quickly** when I add or delete a file (a modification being a combination of delete then add). Also, one should end up with the same "state" even if the same set of operations are performed in any random order.

#### Adding A File

- Generate the file's md5
- Calculate the md5's numerical value (`x`).
- Add `x` to the sum
- Multiply the product by `x`
- Increment the number of items.

#### Removing A File

- Generate the file's md5
- Calculate the md5's numerical value (`x`).
- Subtract `x` from the sum
- Divide the product by `x`
- Decrement the number of items.

#### Problems

Since the numerical representations of hashes can be quite large, I may have to use a library to generate results using strings rather than integers which may be quite slow.

With the limited testing I have done, I have not been able to create "collisions" where a collision is where two different sets of file hashes could produce the same state (remember that we are ignoring the order of the file hashes).

### Question

I'm sure that I can't be the first person to want to achieve such a thing. Is there an algorithm or iterative hash function that aims to do the same thing already, preferably in PHP, Java, or Python? Is there a term for this type of thing, all I could think of was "iterative hash"? Is there a flaw with this algorithm that I haven't spotted, such as with "collisions" making generated state representations non-unique?

Comment: In Java you can use `BigInteger` for your calculations, a bit cumbersome but not too bad.

Comment: If the first file's hash value was 3. It would be 3.3.1 then -> 0.1.0 then if your second files hash value was 4 it would be 4.4.1 so yes. (update - comment replying to seems to have disappeared)

Comment: @biziclop, thanks I'll use that in a Java implementation first if nobody manages to poke a hole in this idea.

Comment: While your home-grown, ad-hoc method might serve your purposes just fine, you may also want to investigate something like [counting Bloom filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Counting_filters) which would be a more standard approach.

Comment: The product of hashes is not necessarily a good thing to store - lots of different numbers can have the same product. Are you sure this is really the best approach?

Comment: I'd skip the multiplication step. Assuming you use multiplication modulo the word size (as C/C++/Java do), then it is highly likely that the product will be 0 if you have enough files. (The expected number of trailing 0s in the product is half the number of files, because of the nature of multiplication.)

Comment: @templatetypedef yes, different sets (of the same length) of numbers quite often result in the same product, and the same goes for the sum, but how many different sets of numbers can you make that produce both the same product AND the sum (ignoring order).

Answer (score 0):

How many states can your file system take ? infinity for all practical purposes.

How long is your hash length ? short enough to be efficient, finite in any case.

Will I get collisions ? Yes.

So, your hash approach seems fine, particularly if it spreads correctly points that are close, i.e. the state of the fs differing by content of just one file hashes to very different values.

However, you should depend on your hash to produce collisions in the long run, it's a mathematical certainty that probability goes to one that someday you get a collision, given that collision chance is not 0.

So to be really safe, you probably need a full MD5 exchange, if speed and fast updates are the goal your scheme sounds good, but I would back it up with more infrequent exchanges of longer keys, just to be on the safe side if sync is mission critical.

Comment: Also multplication and division as well as add and subtract won't work as reversible operations due to overflow.The only reversible operation you can do on two words (bits) is XOR, anything else is non reversible.

Comment: Unsigned arithmetic is modulo a large power of 2, so addition and subtraction of unsigned integers is absolutely reversible. Multiplication (modulo a large power of 2) is not very useful, though, since if you multiply more than a few hundred random values, it is very likely that the result will be 0.

Comment: @rici thanks for the input. I will have to find a different mathematical relationship to replace the multiply/divide or use some code that can handle multiplication of infinitely sized numbers which is likely to be extremely slow or run out of memory (haven't tried yet). http://1-armed-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/multiplying-large-numbers-in-java.html

Comment: I think in your case, I would simply sort the files, then concatenate their MD5, and finally compute an MD5 on this large string (sometimes called a digest). MD5 is pretty fast in my experience, so hashing the digest is ok. You end up with an MD5 key, of length you can choose. Sure, you get some computation time overhead, but this scheme is "solid", it WILL work fine from crypto point of view. Note that sorting the files is essential so that you get the same key on different machines.